# How is this JavaScript code working without invoking the functions?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

This is the codepen of the code https://codepen.io/p5js/pen/wreBKy . Shouldn't the canvas be created only if I call the function with setup(); ?

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
} 

function draw() { 
  background(220);

}
```

Comment: What does `sketch.js` do ? It likely calls `setup` and `draw`.

Comment: @FelixKling nope, `sketch.js` only declares those functions in the global namespace.

Comment: @AndreiGlingeanu: OK `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite, the `setup` and `draw` functions are special, in such a way that `p5` library calls them automatically if it sees them declared by you in the global namespace.

That is, you don't have to call them manually, the library calls them at the most appropriate time for you.

You can read more about that on the [Get Started](https://p5js.org/get-started/) section of the p5 docs.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'll also add that you should **not** try to call `setup()` or `draw()` yourself, as that will short-circuit all the cool stuff P5.js does for you automatically.

Comment: Yes. They are probably doing a `requestAnimationFrame` instead of a poor `setInterval` for the `draw` method. So yeah, definitely don't call them manually.